# Windows 10 IoT Raspberry PI Xaml Question

Tags: windows-iot, c#

All,
First I want to say thank you to all the people who have helped me to get my app as far as I have it. Because of what I needed it was a hard learning curve.
Now I want to improve some of the functionality and efficiency. While everything(except selection of default audio device from code) is working I think it could work better.
One item I am fighting to make work is xBind. I see in the DefaultAPP they were using it for menu items and getting the text and style from a resource.
I added a resource similar to what was in the DefaultApp and used the same line of code in my XAML. However when I run the application I get no text at all. I have looked through the code for the Default app and for the life of me I cannot find how they populated the text in the settings menu. 
Would anyone be willing to shed some light on this?

Currently in my XAML:

```
 <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="48" >
      <TextBlock x:Name="ControlInfo" Text="{Binding[ControlSystemPreferencesText]}" />
</ListViewItem>
```

I have a resource added to the program with a reference to: ControlSystemPreferencesText similar to what was done in the default app.   What I cant figure out is how they are getting the information from the resource to populate the list view items.
I have tried looking through the example program and I cant find where it needs to be referenced.

Comment: might be useful to see the code you have, and where its not working

Comment: and how you are setting the data context, and what the data context is

Comment: I have a name and a value in the resource.resw        this is where I get lost. How to get that information and the text format back to the UI

Comment: You'll need to ensure that `[ControlSystemPreferencesText]` has a value in your `.resw` file. In the sample app these are all in the strings folder in the right language code folders. You might want to check those are all correct.

Comment: it does have a value. value= Control Info.     I think somewhere I am missing the format of this info so it can display?